# htaccess rewrite rule for a URL with a variable is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I Would like to forward

```
www.example.com/list-usernamexyz
```

to

```
www.example.com/profilelist.php?un=usernamexyz
```

I tried it with:

```
RewriteRule ^list-([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profilelist.php?un=$1 [L]
```

others rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?un=$1 [L]
```

but it does not work. What should I change?

Comment: I think RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?un=$1 [L] is doing the trouble. But I need that rule too. any chance to have both rules working?

Comment: Yes, you have a conflict, but as anubhava requested, we need to see your full `.htaccess` file.

Comment: added to the first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?un=$1 [L]` is doing the trouble. But I need that rule too. any chance to have both rules working?

Yes, that rule will certainly conflict with the rule stated in the question. If `/list-usernamexyz` should take priority then you need to ensure that that rule is first in the `.htaccess` file.

Organise your directives like this:

```
# non-www to www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

# Rewrite - profile list
RewriteRule ^list-([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profilelist.php?un=$1 [L]

# Rewrite - profile
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?un=$1 [L]
```

If you are on a shared server then you can remove the first condition that checks the host is not empty. ie. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$`.

If you have plans to implement HSTS then you will need to reverse the two rewrites and have the HTTP to HTTPS redirect before the non-www to www redirect.

Comment: what should I change if the -list would be set after the variable? Like www.example.com/usernamexyz-list. The intuitive RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$-list profilelist.php?un=$1 [L] is not working

Comment: `$` is an end-of-string anchor, so you would need `^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)-list$` instead. Which is the same as `^([\w-]+)-list$`.